# Include local JavaScript within PhoneGap on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application designed to work on multiple mobile platforms. I'm loading a dynamic HTML content from an external page on the Internet using jQuery Mobile. The problematic system is Windows Phone 7.

This is what I get from the external page, with the URL of the script tag already replaced to load from the phone instead of from the net to save bandwidth:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="x-wmapp1:/app/www/test.js"></script>
```

This works fine on Android, iPhone and even BlackBerry when I replaced the *x-wmapp1:* part by a respective counterpart (e.g. file:///android_asset/www/ on Android). However, on Windows Phone 7 it doesn't seem to work at all.

When I try to load the same URL via $.getScript function, it always returns a 404 eror, even if I try and load it with a relative path only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the windows style path using forward slash \'s?

Comment: nope, good point there... will check and see if that works on Monday, thx :)

Comment: Congrats Kiran. It works. I tested the dynamicJSload url function by providing the local URL like dynamicJSload(\\js\\test.js) and it worked. My html file and the js folder are in the same path.

Comment: @Tolis have you tried doing this via PhoneGap 1.8.1? for me, it does not work, and with jQuery's getScript, I get an "invalid argument" error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add your js in the GapSourceDictionary.xml.

The GapSourceDictionary.xml XML file lists all the HTML application resources. When the application starts, this XML file is read and all the files included in the list are added to the isolated storage so that it can be served by the WebBrowser control.

For example your GapSourceDictionary.xml should look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GapSourceDictionary>
        <FilePath Value="www\index.html"/>
        <FilePath Value="www\test.css"/>
        <FilePath Value="www\phonegap-1.3.0.js"/>
        <FilePath Value="www\js\custom.js"/>
    </GapSourceDictionary>
```

In your HTML files use relative path to specify the URL of the external script file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
```

**EDITED**

I managed with success to dynamically load a new local JavaScript file using the following procedure. The test was successful on PhoneGap 2.0. Unfortunately the same test failed on PhoneGap 1.8.1

Below is the source code which loads the JS dynamically:

```
function dynamicJSload(url)
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if (script.readyState)
    {
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "complete" || script.readyState == "loaded"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };
    }
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

In my page I called the function like this:

```
  dynamicJSload("js\\test.js");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer... I already have those files in GapSourceDictionary.xml file and the relative path unfortunatelly gives me an Access Denied error as well

Comment: Could you provide some information about the folders structure? You should have a file www inside the main project's folder and this file  should contain all the HTML, JavaScript, CSS and images.

Comment: If the dynamic HTML content loading is performed through JQ AJAX, please ensure that you have set the dataType to html (dataType: "html"). IE mobile expects exactly the dataType you have set and will not receive the content in case of a wrong dataType.

Comment: I will soon update my answer with a workaround retrieved from the jQuery Forum.

Comment: I successfully managed to load a new JS in a demo page. The test was performed using the Windows Phone 7 Emulator's IE browser. I'll update my post

Comment: ok, I guess we have wandered somewhere completely elsewhere now and I did not realize it, sorry... the problem is NOT loading an external page via AJAX, the problem IS loading an INTERNAL JavaScript file from the URL posted in this question... I also tried your dynamicJSload() function to include an internal file but it failed the same way as it failed with jQuery's getScript()

Comment: so to be clear - I use $.ajax() call to load an external PHP page... source code returned from this $.ajax() call contains SCRIPT tags with JavaScript that are being evaluated by jQuery and included on the page... those SCRIPT tags have internal URL in them (see the question), which should load them from the actual application's www folder, not from the Internet - and that is where it fails

Comment: Tolis, I have awarded you the 150 reputation for your efforts on helping me, unfortunately I cannot accept your answer, as it does not solve this issue for me... I'll try converting to PhoneGap/Cordova version 2.0 and see it it makes a difference later

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I did a copy-paste mistake. The actual code which worked for me is **dynamicJSload(js\\test.js)** and **not** **dynamicJSload(\\js\\test.js)**. My HTML file and the js folder which includes the js files are in the same path, under the HTML folder. As soon as i will find free time, i will update the post with results from several phonegap versions.

Comment: tried to use js\\test.js and it works the same way as if I wrote js/test.js - meaning it tries to load the file from the Internet, not from the local storage

Comment: Hi, the test was successful on PhoneGap 2.0. Unfortunately the same test failed on PhoneGap 1.8.1. I have updated the post. Thanks

Comment: ok, I'll try to replicate this on 2.0 and if it all works, I'll probably accept Kiran's answer

Comment: after upgrading to 2.0, even x-wmapp1:/app/www seems to work now - I have problems making AJAX calls now, but that's for a different question - thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Please try using windows paths like `file:\\\`. Since the file system expects `\` for directory separation that is the most likely issue.

Comment: the file protocol is actually file:///, not file:\\\ ... and the mentioned solution did not work for me unfortunatelly, sorry