# Using jQuery Mobile with phonegap

Tags: android, performance, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I am developing an android application using phonegap for android. As jQuery mobile provide us rich ui components. So I have choose to use jQuery mobile.

Now the problem is that when I am using jQuery mobile it is deceasing application performance.
Means the loading time has been increased. So I just want to know how to use them properly so the application performance will not get affected.

Presently I am inserting like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to package jquery inside your asset/www just like Jason said.
Then add : `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` Inside  tag in androidmanifest.xml like this :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
```

This will render your webview using GPU.

Dont forget to target latest or atleast ICS version for compiling. It can be done in first creation of your apps or edit your androidmanifest.xml :

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

This method proofed worked with my apps. :D

Comment: Thanks let me try I will get back to you. One more problem is coming when i kept the  jquery inside my asset/www just like Jason said the touch events are not working.

Comment: it is already true and when I am using jQuery from www folder its touch events are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would package the jquery libraries with the phoengap application. that way you won't be fetching the resources each time you launch the app from `code.jquery.com`.  This would make your HTML look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also this answer goes in to depth on including JavaScript resources: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12058573/16959

Answer (score 0):

You can use backbone with jQuery mobile [template](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/web-skeletons) which I integrated it and tested it on phonegap and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Beside packaging the jquery libraries with the app you could disable all animations to increase responsiveness, especially on Android devices (animations seems to work reasonable on iOS devices).

```
// Suppress all page transitions
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
});
```