# Slide overlay panel of Jquery mobile not working

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am developing an android application using phonegap for android. As jQuery mobile provide us rich ui components. So I have choose to use jQuery mobile.

Now I have read the tutorials for slide overlay panel from

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/index.html

when I try too use it it is not working. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right"
            data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay">
            <p>Testing Slide panel</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel -->


        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p><a href="#mypanel">open slide overlay panel</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>@Copyrights reserved.</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using older version of jQuery Mobile.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Use 1.3 instead of 1.2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css" />
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using jQuery from the link it not present in my project But if am adding to my www folder then the swipe events are not working... Please see my this thread.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062045/uisng-jquery-mobile-with-phonegap